# Why is AWS CodeBuild failing npm run build step when it is succeeding locally?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I have a ReactJS app that I am building and deploying with AWS CodePipeline.

My CodePipeline is triggered on pushes to Github. For some reason, the build is failing in CodeBuild with error:

```
[Container] 2021/01/18 02:59:02 Running command npm run build

> liferoll-web@0.1.0 build /codebuild/output/src739247890/src
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

./src/App.tsx
Cannot find module: 'package-name'. Make sure this package is installed.

You can install this package by running: npm install package-name.
```

But is succeeding fine on other machines. This is so strange to me as the only place I can reproduce the error is on CodeBuild.

buildspec.yml

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - npm install
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - npm run build
  files:
    - '**/*'
  base-directory: build
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-website",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.3",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.0",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.20",
    "@types/node": "^12.19.13",
    "@types/react": "^16.14.2",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.10",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "react-stacked-carousel": "github:liferoll/react-stacked-carousel",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

App.tsx imports:

```
import React, {useRef, useState} from 'react';
import logo from './assets/liferoll-logo.png';
import iosDownloadSVG from './assets/download-ios.svg'
import qrCode from './assets/qrcode.png'
import loaderGif from './assets/loading.gif'
import clip1 from './assets/clip1.mov'
import clip2 from './assets/clip2.mov'
import clip3 from './assets/clip3.mov'
import clip4 from './assets/clip4.mov'

import './App.css';
//https://github.com/saadqbal/react-stacked-carousel/issues/1
import {StackedCarousel} from 'react-stacked-carousel'
import 'react-stacked-carousel/dist/index.css';
```

I have no idea how to correctly debug this and would appreciate guidance. Posting here to vet-out any obvious issues

Comment: What's in your App.tsx imports?

Comment: Added App.tsx imports to question, don't see how this would matter considering if that was the issue the build would not succeed locally

Comment: `./src/App.tsx Cannot find module: 'package-name'.` seems to indicate wherever CodeBuild is pulling the code from has an import, namely package-name, that does not exist in node_modules

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I am having the same issue with react-router-dom and codeBuild.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons why something would work the way you intend locally, but fail on a remote machine such as CodeBuild.

From the immediate error however, it's telling you that something is not installed or available at the time of building.

```
Cannot find module: 'package-name'. Make sure this package is installed.
```

This may not have to do with a direct import, but an import of something you're importing. My perception is your usage of `"react-stacked-carousel"` is abnormal and highly suspect.